# Adding popup text to Folium FastMarkerCluster markers

Tags: javascript, python, leaflet, folium

With the following code I'm trying to add popup text to my folium FastMarkerCluster markers.
The problem is I can't use variable from Python in JS code to show it value in text on marker.
For instance, how can I use python variable "var" in JS function to show it value in popup text on the marker?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5nTh.png)